# Failed loop: asking the user if they wish to continue (Python)

Tags: python, loops, continue

I developed this code for Python 3 in order to ask the user if they wish to continue:

```
def dnv(): 
    b = input('Would you like to try again? Type 1 for "yes" and 0 for "no": ')
    if b == '1':
        return run()
    if b == '0':
        return print('See you later!')
```

run() is any program's main function. But now I'm taking a course on Python 2 and I've tried to adapt it on an algorithm I took from there, with no success. The objetive was to determine how many days are between two dates. I believe the relevant part is:

```
def inputs():
    year1 = input('Type the first year: ')
    month1 = input('Type the first month: ')
    day1 = input('Type the first day: ')
    year2 = input('Type the second year: ')
    month2 = input('Type the second month: ')
    day2 = input('Type the second day: ')
    print daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2)

def dnv():
    answer = input('Would you like to try again? Type "y" for yes and "n" for no: ')
    if answer == 'y':
        return inputs()
    else:
        print('See you later!')
```

I get a `NameError: name 'y' is not defined` (analogue to 'n') though everytime I type y or n. I've also tried to modify `if answer == 'y'` to:

```
if answer.lower().startswith('y'):
    return inputs()
```

Again with no success. What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: python2 `input()` works differently from python3 `input()`. Try `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Use `raw_input()`

```
answer = input('Would you like to try again? Type "y" for yes and "n" for no: ')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the python 2 you need to change the input to:

```
answer = raw_input("your message here: ")
```

And you don't need to return  a function you can just call it.

```
if answer.lower().startswith('y'):
    inputs()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using python 3, I recommend this:

```
b = input('Would you like to try again? Type 1 for "yes" and 0 for "no": ')
   if b == '1':
       return run()
   if b == '0':
       return print('See you later!')
```